# Google Directory API tokens.list lists apps for some users but not the admin

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

In a particular domain, I installed some apps(Example: Infogram, 5PM, etc.) for the admin and another user. In the directory API methid tokens.list, these apps show up for the second user but are not listed for the admin user.
If the app did not use an OAuth authorization, wouldn't it be excluded from both users' token listing?
If it did, why is it absent in one user and not the other?

Comment: Who's userkey did you use in the tokens.list HTTP request?

Comment: the corresponding user's email address. In the developer's reference document (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/list#try-it) i tried by giving the admin's email and another user's email address